# How to speed up Rails console on windows 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to speed up the Rails console on Windows 7?

Comment: did you use rails installer or just installed ruby and gems then gem installed rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) with any OS, for example Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS and deploy your Rails app in this sandbox. In this way, you will have full unix environment, very close to server environment.