# windows 7 very slow console actions

Tags: windows-7, ruby-on-rails, git, performance

Standard console functions work fast, but when I try to use git  or Ruby on Rails console - actions take too long (like git pull origin master - slow on showing "Enter passphrase", RoR - run server and all rake db commands). In average RoR commands take more than 1 minute.

Comment: I would call it long "ramp up" time, same problem here vote up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, ruby is not optimized for windows.  There are some workarounds, YMMV.

Some options:

- [Stackoverflow question recommending switching to 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627888/rails-on-windows-is-so-slow-rails-v-takes-4-seconds)
- [Custom Windows Ruby Build](http://itreallymatters.net/post/12897174267/speedup-ruby-1-9-3-on-windows)
- [Use a linux VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048844/how-to-speed-up-rails-console-on-windows-7)

Comment: Thinked it is just some bug that I can easy fix. Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

it is fixable

There are some questions in SO for that but [this](http://engineering.gomiso.com/2011/02/25/adventures-in-scaling-part-1-using-ree/) basically sums it up

you need to reset ruby's garbage collector variables

it should make your ruby faster, thus the rest of ruby commands will also be faster